# What is Numpy equivalence of dataframe.loc() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a 120,000*4 numpy array as shown below. Each row is a sample. The first column is time in second, or the `index` using Pandas terminology.

```
0.014      14.175  -29.97  -22.68 
0.022      13.905  -29.835 -22.68
0.030      12.257  -29.32  -22.67
... ...
1259.980   -0.405   2.205   3.825
1259.991   -0.495   2.115   3.735
```

I want to select the rows recorded between 100.000 to 200.000 sec and save it into a new array. If this were a Pandas dataframe, I would simply write `df.loc[100:200]`. What is the equivalent operation in numpy?

This is NOT a question of feasibility. I simply wonder if there are any pythonic one-line solutions.

Comment: As @Wen's answer pointed out, it's a bit different if the first column isn't sorted. I should have specified the condition

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This assumes indexes are sorted:

IIUC,

```
x=np.array([ [1,2,3,4],
           [5,6,7,8],
           [9,10,11,12],
           [13,14,15,16]])

x[(x[:,0] >= 5) & (x[:,0] <= 9) ]
```

So you would have 100 and 200 instead of 5 and 9.

---

For a more general solution, check [Wen`s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509221/2535611)

Comment: I think this will not fully replace .loc , see my answer

Comment: Learning "IIUC" :) https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IIUC I like that acronym

Comment: If speed is of the essence,  apply numba to it. Eg  if you want to get to an individual number in the above array e.g where the second item in the row is 6 give me the 3rd item in that row (=7)  timeit x[x[:,1]==6][:,2][0]  # 4.05 µs ± 171 ns   but with numba:   @jit(nopython = True)  
def findresult(array,x,y):  
    return array[array[:,1]==x][:,y][0]    timeit findresult(x,6,2)   # 998 ns ± 136 ns per loop

Answer (score 6):

Data from Raf

```
x[np.where(x[:,0]==5)[0][0]:np.where(x[:,0]==9)[0][0]+1,:]
Out[341]: 
array([[ 5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Notice

only using greater and less than for that can not fully replace the `.loc`, the back end of .loc is index position not value range

For example

```
df
Out[348]: 
       0   1   2   3
0      1   2   3   4
1      5   6   7   8
4444   9  10  11  12
3     13  14  15  16

df.loc[1:3]
Out[347]: 
       0   1   2   3
1      5   6   7   8
4444   9  10  11  12
3     13  14  15  16
```

Comment: Awesome, I mistakenly assumed indexes are sorted ;) +1

Comment: very cool, I didn't consider this behavior of `.loc` either. Rafael's answer is what I was looking for, but yours is the technically correct one